# How to GET a complete class from parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im currenlty trying out parse.com to use it as a repository for sensor messages. I do some data science with those messages using python but when trying to GET the class where I have the entries I can only GET a maximum of 1000. I though a possibility would be to run a job that export all the entries to a csv or json, can that be done on the cloud code platform?

Answer (score 1):

Queries provide `skip`, so the nice way to do this in cloud/JS is to chain promises recursively, skipping the count of objects already retrieved:

```
function unboundedQuery(query, array) {
    array = array || [];
    query.limit(1000);
    query.skip(array.length);
    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        array.push(results);
        return (results.length == 1000)? runQuery(query, array) : array;
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var query = new Parse.query("Class");
// qualify, sort, etc, but no need to set limit or skip
unboundedQuery(query).then(function(results) {
    // results will contain all objects in "Class", unless it timed out
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ***query.skip(10000)*** code to get more but skip cannot be larger than 10000.

Or you can use this simple code to export entire class

https://github.com/mkim871/parse-node-backup